# Create an OAuth 2.0 service provider using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api, oauth-provider

I'm building a web app which will have an api and an authorization service using DotNetOpenAuth. I found [this example](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/dotnetopenauth-oauth-and-mvc-for-dummies/) on how you can authorize using a service provider that already exists but I would like an example on how to implement a service provider that can create tokens, persist them and do evaluation. Is there any great articles or sample providers that I can download?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Update*

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) has moved on since this was initially posted. I strongly suggest you follow Ashish's advise and take a look at the samples. It contains code to write Authorization Servers, Resource Servers and Clients for all the major flows.

**If you wanted a pre built solution, with opensource code**

Thinktecture Identity Server is an Open Source .NET security token service. It supports a number of endpoints for authentication including OAuth 2.0 Bearer tokens.

*Update* this Thinktecture Identity Server is now on [version 2](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/wiki) and supports these OAuth 2.0 flows

1. Resource Owner Password Credential Flow
2. Implict Flow & JavaScript
3. Authorization Code Flow

again take a look at the code to see how it was all done and there are samples [here](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/tree/master/samples) to show how to plumb it in.

I hope this helps - these library's and examples have hugely helped us over the past few months.

*Update*

There is also another example **warning, it looks dated** of a simple OAuth provider for MVC [here](http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/18/oauth-2-0-for-mvc-two-legged-implementation.aspx) Sample code [here](http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/downloads/detail?name=OAuth2.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges)

Comment: 404 page not found in "following controller" bah

Answer (score 2):

There are complete working example for DotNetOpenAuth can be found here - https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 1):

I tried a number of times with DNOA....had to give up, but documented my findings (used Thinktecture in the end)...http://tb-it.blogspot.co.nz/2015/06/oauth-20-frameworks-and-platforms.html